# How to bind an already existing function to work when i toggle the slide, in angular

Tags: angular, toggle

I have a function that loads some graphs of countries, when I open the application.
I need to bind this function to a toggle slide ( toggles between Countries Graph (default in off/false stage) and State Graph).How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to bind it with the on click event of the toggle component. Be careful though because you should distinguish which one is calling that method.